# Iterar horarios con carbon y laravel

Tags: php, laravel, carbon

Hola tengo el siguiente código con carbon en donde quiero que me de un array con la hora de inicio hasta la hora final cada 30 min. No me funciona. Alguna sugerencia.

```
            $inicio = $horario[0]->end_date; // 08:00:00
            $final = $horario[1]->start_date; // 12:00:00

            $cerrado = array(); //added
            $h = 0;
            $i = Carbon::parse($inicio)->toTimeString();
            $f = Carbon::parse($final)->toTimeString();

            while($i <= $f){
                $cerrado[] = Carbon::parse($inicio)->copy()->addMinute($h)->format('H:i:s');

                $h=$h+30;
            }
            dd($cerrado);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sin usar carbon y basandonos en las clases que proporciona PHP [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/es/book.datetime.php), [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/es/class.dateinterval.php) y [`DatePeriod`](http://php.net/manual/es/class.dateperiod.php) puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
<?php
$inicio = new DateTime( '2018-11-28 08:00:00');
$fin = new DateTime( '2018-11-28 12:00:00');

$intervalo = new DateInterval('PT30M');

$fechas = new DatePeriod($inicio, $intervalo, $fin);

foreach($fechas as $fecha){
    echo $fecha->format("d-m-Y H:i:s") . "<br>";
}
?>
```

Resultado:

```
28-11-2018 08:00:00
28-11-2018 08:30:00
28-11-2018 09:00:00
28-11-2018 09:30:00
28-11-2018 10:00:00
28-11-2018 10:30:00
28-11-2018 11:00:00
28-11-2018 11:30:00
```

Si solo quieres mostrar las horas o con otro formato diferente, te bastaria con ajustar `$fecha->format("d-m-Y H:i:s")`, info en [`DateTime::format`](http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.format.php).

Comment: Holam no funciona me tiene el error, Type error: Argument 1 passed to Faker\Provider\Base::__construct() must be an instance of Faker\Generator, string given, called in

Comment: @JuanJose Como estas usando Laravel debes indicar el namespace en este caso como son clases de PHP basta con añadir una barra invertida `\DateTime`, `\DateInterval` y `\DatePeriod`, si aun asi te sigue sin funcionar, edita la pregunta y añade el metodo completo, para poder ayudarte. un saludo.